# UPDATE FROM SELECT

Tags: oracle, select

i have to do update from a select i got this 2 tables with this rows

**T1**

```
customer_number | trx number     | amount_due_remaining
____________________________________________________
309514          |MM1218881/2011  | 0
309514          |MM1218882/2011  | 0
309514          |MM1218903/2011  | 0
309514          |MM1218905/2011  | 0
```

**T2**

```
contract | numdoc         | import
___________________________________
309514 |MM1218881/2011  | 2000,77
309514 |MM1218882/2011  | 1000,45
309514 |MM1218903/2011  | 1000,23
309514 |MM1218905/2011  | 2500,12
```

i have to put in T2 the values of T1 of the column amount_due_remaining into import

i do this query

```
update dbestrconto T1
SET T1.IMPORTO = (
SELECT nvl(T2.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING,0)
FROM XXENE_V_CCML_TRANSACTIONS@XXENE T2
WHERE T2.customer_number=T1.contratto
AND T2.customer_number='3095614'
and T2.TRX_NUMBER=T1.NUMDOC
)
```

but is wrong, please help me.

Regards, Rodolfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are updating all the rows - you need to add a where clause to you UPDATE.

i would recommend using MERGE instead.

```
merge into dbestrconto  t1 
using xxene_v_ccml_transactions@xxene t2
on  (t2.customer_number=t1.contratto
and t2.trx_number=t1.numdoc)
when matched then update set 
    t1.importo = nvl(t2.amount_due_remaining,0)
where  t2.customer_number='3095614';
```

Regards. Haki.